# Open API Specification Version 2.0

Tags: web-services, spring-mvc, jax-rs, google-cloud-endpoints, openapi-generator

We need to create the openapi v2.0 specification documents for APIs. We are using spring mvc (version 4) framework and build restful web services using JAX-RS. Need to create the openapi.yaml file to upload to Google Cloud Platform to configure Google Cloud Endpoints

Comment: What's the question? Are you looking for tutorials or tips? Have you tried something that didn't work? More details would help. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Looking for tutorials

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I'm afraid tutorial requests are [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) on Stack Overflow. Please try searching for tutorials yourself, and come back with specific questions if you run into issues with implementation.

Comment: You may find [Swagger Editor](https://swagger.io/tools/swagger-editor/) helpful to learn OpenAPI spec 2.0

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution with this tutorial
http://mrbool.com/use-case-documenting-a-jax-rs-api-with-swagger/36735